# How do I delete black faces/dark holes?

Tags: faces

[image]

I was modeling an ak47 and this happened. I tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all but it didn't fix the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean with delete 'blank face'?

Comment: but i think you would want to fill with F

Comment: by black faces i mean black squeres like that in that pic (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: i mean is it actually a face with black material?

Comment: or is it empty?

Comment: That looks like a hole to me rather than a face.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Please add a screenshot of that place with all the vertices around it selected; that would help to diagnose if there's a face or not. Also note that if you [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) the file that would help to find problem more quickly.

Comment: That bis not a blank/dark face, there is no geometry there, that is a hole. Just fill it with `F`

Comment: Select the vertices surrounding the hole and fill it with 'F'